# What is this Error when Debug android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got this error when I tried to debug my app

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method requestPermissions([Ljava/lang/String;I)V in class Lcom/cscodetech/townclap/activity/LoginActivity; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.zestar.myclip.activity.LoginActivity' appears in /data/app/com.zestar.myclip-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)
        at com.zestar.myclip.activity.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:92)
```

The logcat pointed to this line of code

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
```

What is wrong with that line

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        custPrograssbar = new CustPrograssbar();
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(LoginActivity.this);
        atCode.setOnFocusChangeListener((view, b) -> {
            if (!b) {
                // on focus off
                String str = atCode.getText().toString();

                ListAdapter listAdapter = atCode.getAdapter();
                for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    String temp = listAdapter.getItem(i).toString();
                    if (str.compareTo(temp) == 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                atCode.setText("");

            }
        });
        getCodelist();
    }
```

Comment: `requestPermissions` is a static method on the activity class (check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int))). You should probably call something like `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, perms, code)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as `requestPermissions` like [@TylerV](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#request-permission) said, try using this way instead
as instructed in
[Documentation for how to request app permissions | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#request-permission)

this should be the right way to request permissions in fragments which goes as this:

1. You first initialize this variable in fragment/activity which specifies what should happen if the permissions were granted or not:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher requestPermissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), result -> { {
                    //result is a map(string permission,boolean granted or not)
                    //to check if all permissions were granted or not
                    if(result.containsValue(false)){ 
                    // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because
                    // the features requires a permission that the user has denied.
                    // At the same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to
                    // system settings in an effort to convince the user to change
                    // their decision.
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't continue without the required permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else { 
                       //continue your work flow
                    }
                        
                });
```

2. Then when you need to request for a permission you call launch on the object you declared with an array holding the permission you're requesting :

```
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||  
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||   
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) {

                    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION});

            } else // continue your work
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your logs when exception occurs. Maybe error is because of android version. You must check if android version is bigger than Api level 26 (Marshmallow):

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
     requestPermissions(INITIAL_PERMS, INITIAL_REQUEST);
 }
```